# My device is not showing up in the schemes

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, ios6.1

My iPod touch runs iOS 6.1, and Xcode 4.5.2 deployment target supported is iOS SDK 6.0.

Is this the reason behind the fact my iPod touch doesn't figure on the schemes list? Should I upgrade Xcode to support iOS 6.1 deployment? Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, iOS 6.1 support is a new feature of Xcode 4.6, so you have to upgrade.

If you open the "Organizer" window in Xcode 4.5 and go to the "Devices" tab, you should see the iPod device and a message that the iOS version is not supported.